# How can I get updated content after a click?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am tring to find a solution for this problem.

1. Open a page anche get the specific links
2. Click on a link (pagination link) to get the second page of results
3. Read the new content an get the new links again....

This is a piece of my casperjs app:

```
var page = 1;

function getLinks() {    
    var links = __utils__.getElementsByXPath('//div[@class="myDiv"]//a');

    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href')
    });
}

casper.start("www.example.com", function(){
   //
})

casper.repeat(2, function() {

    this.then(function(){
        links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
        links = links.concat(links);    
    });

    this.then(function(){
        page++;    
        this.clickLabel(String(page), 'a');
    });

});
```

As you can see I have two steps inside repeat. I have set 2 because I only need to check two pages.

At the moment my problem is the "click" . It works, because the new Url is called but the problem is that the first step will be immediately executed so the new content is not fully loaded. So, when I call getLinks() again I still work on the previous content.

I obviously would like to getLinks when the page is completely loaded. How can I do it ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could prepend a [`wait`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#wait) before retrieving the links like this:

```
casper.repeat(2, function() {
    this.wait(2000); // 2 seconds

    this.then(function(){
        links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
        links = links.concat(links);    
    });

    this.then(function(){
        page++;
        this.clickLabel(String(page), 'a');
    });

});
```

You could also append a [`waitForResource`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforresource) after the click to make sure that the page is loaded. I assume here that the page number is inside of the URL as `page=x`:

```
casper.repeat(2, function() {
    this.then(function(){
        links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
        links = links.concat(links);    
    });

    this.then(function(){
        page++;
        this.clickLabel(String(page), 'a');
    });

    this.waitForResource(new RegExp("page="+page));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

FAQ how can I delay some code so that it gives the virtual browser time to load and/or render the results of a click or other JavaScript action on the page?

```
window.setTimeout(
    function () {
        // process page here
    },
    2000 // number of milliseconds to wait (here 2s)
);
```

Pretty easy, isn't it! In your case you would:

```
do_click();
window.setTimeout(
    function () { process_click_result(); },
    2000 // 2 seconds
);
```

Comment: `setTimeout` is not applicable to this scenario, because casper will just execute the next scheduled step and exit before even the timeout is run out.